# How to exclude the area of ​intersecting polygons from the total sample?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

**machine translation**

I am interested in solving such a problem. There is a table

```
id | coordsPolygon
 1 | 0103000020E6100 ...
 2 | 01030000301F300 ...
...
```

I have to make a query that returns the total surface area covered by polygons. However, there are polygons that intersect with each other, or enter into each other, which adds to the usual query type
`sum (ST_Area (coordsPolygon))` excess area.

Question: how can I get the total surface area covered by polygons?

---

интересует решение такой проблемы. Есть таблица

`id|coordsPolygon
 1 |0103000020E6100...
 2 |01030000301F300...
...`

Я должен произвести запрос, который возвращает общую площадь поверхности,  покрываемой полигонами. Однако есть полигоны, которые пересекаются друг с другом, либо входят друг в друга, что добавляет к обычному запросу типа 
`sum(ST_Area(coordsPolygon))`
лишнюю площадь.

Вопрос: как я могу получить общую площадь поверхности,  покрываемой полигонами?

Comment: Simple, but costly for large tables: `SELECT ST_Area(ST_Union(coordsPolygon)) FROM <your_table>;`

Comment: @ThingumaBob, oh well, thanks :)